# Rails Responder redirect to index in create causes form strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller, I have this:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  # code...

  def create
    @test = current_user.tests.create(params[:test])
    respond_with @test, location: tests_url
  end

  # code...

end
```

That's cool, when I create the `test`, it redirects to `test#index` (as expected), *but*, if I press `F5`, the browser asks me to resubmit the form.

If I remove the `location` statement from `respond_with` it works just fine, but doesn't go to URL I want.

How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT

I change my method to

```
@test = current_user.tests.new(params[:transaction])
respond_with(@test) do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to "/tests/" } if @test.save
end
```

And it works.. but, It's kinda weird I had to use a String instead of `tests_url`.

---

### EDIT 2

See this [complete example code](https://github.com/caarlos0/respond-with) amd the 
[Bug report](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9271).

---

### EDIT 3

I'm unable to reproduce it with Ruby 1.9.3-p327, only in -p385.

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/

Comment: why you are concerned about pressing `F5`? Why anyone want to do that ? It's purpose is to refresh the page and since your browser data gets refreshed, it is asking for resubmit.

Comment: But, pressing F5 in index page, after a while, resubmit the form is a really strange behavior for me...

Comment: well, I tried your link @checkit, same issue..

Comment: @caarlos0: `redirect_to tests_path` didn't work for you?

Comment: nop, same issue... really, really weird.. @PinnyM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `redirect_to` method, like this:

```
def create
  @test = current_user.tests.create(params[:test])
  respond_with @test do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tests_path }
  end
end
```

Then, if the client asks for a json response, the default `to_json` behavior will be triggered, but if the response format desired is html, then a redirect will be sent.

Comment: same issue. I found it's probably my ruby version (-p385)

Comment: Anyway, I rollback ruby (from p385 to p327) and my chrome (from 26 to 24) and it works like a charm now. As you give the only answer, I mark it as accepted. Thanks.